# index a csv file solr - missing content stream

Tags: solr

```
Error is as follows :
[root@hdqsltest1 garyTestDocs]# curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv? literal.id=book2&commit --data-binary @sample.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf- 8'
[1] 16541
bash: commit: command not found
```

Response looks like this -

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 missing content stream</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update/csv. Reason:
<pre>    missing content stream</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small>     </i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

sample.csv input -

```
 module,meets,question,response
 General Questions,,"Please provide us a detailed company background","We are great"
```

schema.xml -

```
 <field name="module" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="meets" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="question" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="response" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

solrconfig.xml

```
 <!-- CSV update handler, loaded on demand -->

  <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler" startup="lazy">
       <lst name="defaults"> 
             <str name="separator">,</str>
             <str name="header">true</str>
             <str name="encapsulator">"</str>
        </lst> 
   </requestHandler>
```

Another sample.csv

```
   module,meets,question,response
   General Questions,,"Please provide us a detailed company background","Yes"
```

I have enabled remote streaming. my query is

```
   curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?literal.id=book12&commit=true --data-binary @sample.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

So what am i doing wrong. Please guide.

Version of solr = 3.6.2.

The whole point of indexing it is to be able to query over fields ? I am also wondering if a csv file can be extracted to place its text in various fields, i know it places the text of the csv file in content field. Any suggestions on the update/extract ? I have asked 2 qns here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually just solved the problem with this query

curl http://localhost.com:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true --data-binary @sample.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'

but prior to executing this query , i was constantly getting required id field error and i would go to my query and mention literal.id=ABC1 (some random id which is unique) and then i still got the same error. so i went to my schema.xml and deleted the required attributed for field id and restarted solr and ran the query above and still got the error. so the solution came when i created an id column in my sample.csv and it indexed it. I actually don't like that ! but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have remote streaming enabled, you need to specify the content type and file as query params in your request.

Here is an example from [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV#Example)

Specifically, your querystring would look somewhat like this -

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?stream.file=<remote path>/sample.csv&stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

Note that with remote streaming, you need to ensure that the location of the file is accessible to Solr instance.

Comment: I continue to get the same error ! What is a content stream ? I just dont't understand what is going wrong ? i was able to index a sample csv file like id,author,title (1st row) 1,sanjay,ABC (2nd row), 2,Ajay,XYZ (3rd row). I was able to index this file but it just wont index the sample.csv file mentioned above with blank spaces and quotes.

Comment: Oh - I missed the quotes part - you will have to escape quotes while indexing. It is a special character. [These special characters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) need to be escaped by adding a `\` character in front.

Comment: could you pls clarify ? also i am pondering if you see my sample.csv file above it has a blank space ? could that be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

firstly change directory to found your csv file,

```
cd <file_path>
```

and

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true --data-binary @sample.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

Run this script from terminal. I hope solve your problem.